# Proof that a matrix is invertible regarding changes of base

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am struggling with the concepts behind this question and ones like it quite a bit, so a concise explanation would be nice. If we let $T : U \to V$ be an invertible linear map, and let $A = [F, T, E]$ for some choice of bases $E$ of $U$ and $F$ of $V$, I want to prove that A is invertible. I believe that if T is invertible then I can say $A^-1$ exists through the correspondence between linear maps and matrices but I am not sure how to show it for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since T is invertible then $U$ and $V$ must have the same dimension. For any $E$ and $F$, $[F,T,E]$ is a square matrix. In addition $det(E)\neq0$ and $det(F)\neq0$. Let $A=[I_V,T,I_U]$. We have $det(A)\neq0$. Hence $det([F,T,E])=det(F^{-1}AE)=det(F)^{-1}det(A)det(E)\neq0$. Thus $[F,T,E]$ is invertible.